# C++ template: Possible to behave differently for type with default constructor vs. without?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

The simplest way to think of what I'm trying to achieve is that I'm creating my own smart pointer (or smart reference) such that when the wrapped type has a default constructor the template will encapsulate the type directly, whereas when there is no default constructor the type will use a pointer to the object.

To better understand what I'm doing: I'm creating a lazy initialization (deferred initialization) template. The real goal here is that I'd like my wrapper to avoid heap allocation but still work for types where there is no default constructor and therefore I can't directly encapsulate it and still defer initialization until sometime after the constructor.

For example, I'd like the case where there is a default constructor to behave something like this:

```
template <class T> class Wrapper {
    T   _t;
};
```

And the case where there is no default constructor to behave something list this:

```
template <class T> class Wrapper {
    T*  _t;
};
```

I suspect that the best I could do is to have two templates, eg. WrapperRef and WrapperPtr, or a single class but use it as Wrapper or Wrapper.

I'm free to use any version of C++, though would prefer not to use compiler-specific features although would consider it if it makes this all possible. Non-portability of code is less of a concern for this particular case, so think of it as more of a though exercise.

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to c++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible

Comment: Looks like a job for an optional type, e.g. `boost::optional`, or in C++17, [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Comment: @RichardHodges: Caveat: [_maybe_ not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13786482/560648) (but probably yes)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the pointers. @Nicol: Thanks for the reference to the original question -- I agree mine is a duplicate, though I was unable to find that original when searching before asking mine.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e727d9bb87a62e8f